User is null on direct link navigation firebase
How can I redirect to my home page when user doesn't have the required permissions to access a page. I'm using this custom made AuthGuard
import { ReactNode, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

import { useFirebaseAuth } from '@/contexts/FirebaseAuthContext';
import { can } from '@/lib/acl';
import { Loader } from '@/components/Loader';

export type ChildrenType = {
  children: ReactNode;
  requiredPermission?: { action: string; subject: string };
};

export default function AuthGuard({
                                    children,
                                    requiredPermission
                                  }: ChildrenType) {
  const { user, role, loading } = useFirebaseAuth();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isAuthorized, setIsAuthorized] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Loading', loading);
    console.log('AuthGuard user', user);
    if (!loading) {
      if (user && role && requiredPermission) {
        if (!can(role, requiredPermission.action, requiredPermission.subject)) {
          router.push('/dashboard');
          setIsAuthorized(false);
        } else {
          setIsAuthorized(true);
        }
      }
      // else {
      //   // Redirect to home if he's not logged in (no user)
      //   router.push('/home');
      // }
    }
  }, [role, loading, requiredPermission, router, user]);

  if (loading || !isAuthorized) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  return <>{children}</>;
}

Unfortunately with this AuthGuard, if I comment out the router.push to home I always get redirected to the home page when I navigate to the link directly for both authenticated and unauthenticated users, so I commented it out and now it works correctly for authenticated user. I can navigate directly to a link that is protected and not get redirected to home page for an authenticated user, but now the problem is I want to still redirect to home page for unauthenticated user
Edit
useFirebaseAuth hook
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { onAuthStateChanged, sendPasswordResetEmail, signOut, User } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '@/config/firebase/utils';
import { Role } from '@/store/types';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { clearUserSubscriptionData } from '@/store/slices/userSubscriptionSlice';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { AppDispatch } from '@/store';
import { useUserSubscription } from '@/hooks/useUserSubscription';

interface AuthContextType {
  user: User | null;
  role: Role;
  loading: boolean;
  logout: () => Promise<void>;
  sendForgotPasswordEmail: (email: string) => Promise<void>;
}

const FirebaseAuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType | null>(null);

export const FirebaseAuthProvider: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const [role, setRole] = useState<Role>(Role.VISITOR);
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const { fetchUserSubscription } = useUserSubscription();

  useEffect(() => {
    const authStateChange = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
      setLoading(true);
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
        const token = await user.getIdTokenResult();
        await fetchUserSubscription();
        const role = token.claims.role
          ? (token.claims.role as Role)
          : Role.GUEST;
        setRole(role);
      } else {
        setUser(null);
        setRole(Role.VISITOR);
        dispatch(clearUserSubscriptionData());
      }
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return () => authStateChange();
  }, [auth, user, dispatch]);

  const sendForgotPasswordEmail = async (email: string) => {
    try {
      await sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Unable to send password reset email. Please try again.');
    }
  };

  const logout = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      await signOut(auth);
      setUser(null);
      setRole(Role.VISITOR);
      dispatch(clearUserSubscriptionData());
      router.push('/home');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Logout Error:', error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <FirebaseAuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        role,
        loading,
        logout,
        sendForgotPasswordEmail
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </FirebaseAuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useFirebaseAuth = () => {
  const context = useContext(FirebaseAuthContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(
      'useFirebaseAuth must be used within a FirebaseAuthProvider'
    );
  }
  return context;
};

And here is my console logs when I'm authenticated and try to access a authenticated page (Good)
Loading false AuthGuard.tsx:22:12
AuthGuard user null AuthGuard.tsx:23:12
Loading false AuthGuard.tsx:22:12
AuthGuard user null AuthGuard.tsx:23:12
Loading true AuthGuard.tsx:22:12
AuthGuard user Object { … }
AuthGuard.tsx:23:12
Loading true AuthGuard.tsx:22:12
AuthGuard user Object {  … }
AuthGuard.tsx:23:12
Loading false AuthGuard.tsx:22:12
AuthGuard user Object { … }
AuthGuard.tsx:23:12
Loading false AuthGuard.tsx:22:12
AuthGuard user Object { … }

When I'm unauthenticated and access a authenticated page (Not good, keeps loading)
Loading false AuthGuard.tsx:22:12
AuthGuard user null AuthGuard.tsx:23:12
Loading false AuthGuard.tsx:22:12
AuthGuard user null AuthGuard.tsx:23:12
Loading false AuthGuard.tsx:22:12
AuthGuard user null


Can you edit your question to show the output of your console.log statements? I've never used useFirebaseAuth (so a link would be appreciated), but would assume it listens to the auth state, which will only get a value once Firebase has restored the user data from the browser's local storage.

useFirebaseAuth is my custom made hook, I'll edit and add it to my question and your assumption is right!

"When I'm unauthenticated and access a authenticated page (Not good, keeps loading)" Isn't that exactly what you do here: if (loading || !isAuthorized) { return <Loader />; }

There is a logic problem in your AuthGuard, loading is always true on first render when the useFirebaseAuth hook is called. So the useEffect will directly push to /home:
    if (!loading) {
      if (user && role && requiredPermission) {
        if (!can(role, requiredPermission.action, requiredPermission.subject)) {
          router.push('/dashboard');
          setIsAuthorized(false);
        } else {
          setIsAuthorized(true);
        }
      }
      // else {
      //   // Redirect to home if he's not logged in (no user)
      //   router.push('/home');
      // }
    }

Try this instead:
import { ReactNode, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useFirebaseAuth } from '@/contexts/FirebaseAuthContext';
import { can } from '@/lib/acl';
import { Loader } from '@/components/Loader';

export type ChildrenType = {
  children: ReactNode;
  requiredPermission?: { action: string; subject: string };
};

export default function AuthGuard({
  children,
  requiredPermission,
}: ChildrenType) {
  const { user, role, loading } = useFirebaseAuth(); // Get user, role, and loading state from Firebase context
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isAuthorized, setIsAuthorized] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // If the authentication state is still loading, do nothing
    if (loading) {
      return;
    }

    if (!user) {
      // If no user is logged in, redirect to the home page
      router.push('/home');
      setIsAuthorized(false);
    } else if (requiredPermission && role) {
      // If user and role exist, check for permissions
      if (!can(role, requiredPermission.action, requiredPermission.subject)) {
        // If the user doesn't have the required permissions, redirect to the dashboard
        router.push('/dashboard');
        setIsAuthorized(false);
      } else {
        setIsAuthorized(true);
      }
    }
  }, [loading, user, role, requiredPermission, router]);

  if (loading || !user || !isAuthorized) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  return <>{children}</>;
}

And do not forget, that you are using the AuthGuard as a client component which pretty much makes it useless for security purposes, but I guess you are just using it for some UI/UX stuff

Yes thank you I will try this. Unfortunately firebase auth is ran in the client side so I can't really use nextjs server middleware to check if the user is authenticated. And yes this is for UI/UX reason, the backend is still secured

I dont know your usecase and other details, but I prefer ie supabase > firebase in the context of a next.js app

Why is that? Thanks

Supabase and next.js are good friends, you will find much more guidance and well written documentation when it's about integration of supabase in next.js. plus supabase is fully open source, firebase just partially.
